# Print matrix as black and white squares, similar to QR code

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, unicode, qr-code

I am implementing a micro QR code generator in C++ and I want to print the final matrix that is generated as a set of black and white squares to look like a real QR code. My matrix is made up of integer values of `1` and `0` (there is a reason in my code for that, instead of using boolean values) and I want to print a black square for a value of `1` or a white square for a value of `0`.

My current code (see below or test it [here](http://ideone.com/WqTnNY)) uses Unicode characters `\u2b1c` and `\u2b1b` to achieve a result similar to what I want but it is not square enough to be scanned by a QR code scanner.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int i,j;
int printPixels(int Board[11][11]){
    for (i=0;i<11;i++){
        for (j=0;j<11;j++)  cout << ((Board[i][j] == 0) ? "\u2b1c" : "\u2b1b");
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    int a[11][11]={
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
        {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
        {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1}
    };
    printPixels(a);
}
```

**Limitations**

- I can only use ASCII or Unicode characters to do this and not any drawing library or package (the reason for this is complicated, but this is my specification).
- I need the implementation to be as platform-independent as possible and look good enough to scan if possible with a common QR code scanner.
- I would like it to look good on something like [Ideone](http://ideone.com), which has a white background instead of the usual black background of most terminals.

Comment: Have you tried with a space and \u2588 (maybe doubled) like [here](https://ideone.com/v6i7cZ)?

Comment: @Bob__ that is actually a very good solution, could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible alternative is to use space character for 0 and Unicode Character 'FULL BLOCK' (U+2588) █ to represent 1.

```
(Board[i][j] == 0) ? "  " : "\u2588\u2588";
```

You can see how it looks like [here](https://ideone.com/v6i7cZ) where I also used a pair of each character to take into account the font aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I used smaller block symbols than full block and whitespace in my program, please take a look here: https://github.com/Y2Z/qr

█, whitespace, ▀, and ▄ make the resulting QR Code to be four times more compact than when generated only by using █ and whitespace.

Hope it helps!